# In a qt project, how to add include path to pro under windows where the path contains space

Tags: windows, qt

I want to add this C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include to my .pro file.
How can I acheive that?
thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Write it between double quotes..

```
win32 {

    INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include"
    ...
}
```