# Qt Creator include path

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm making a project in Qt Creator and I wanted to add include path so I added to `.pro` file this:

```
INCLUDEPATH +=  "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.2\include\"
```

I tried also replacing `\` with `\\\`. How should I add this?

Answer (score 1):

Do as here [In a qt project, how to add include path to pro under windows where the path contains space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717359/in-a-qt-project-how-to-add-include-path-to-pro-under-windows-where-the-path-con). Don't forget to save your `.pro` file after modification.

Good luck!

Comment: What is your problem, what kind of error did you get? Why do you say that this didnt work?

Comment: I get 'Cannot open include file: 'cppconn\driver.h': No such file or directory'

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote items containing spaces in qmake variables with $$quot():

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$quot(C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.2\include\)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use custom command for qmake in Projects/Build/Build Steps section in "Additional arguments" like this: 
`"QT+=your_qt_modules" "DEFINES+=your_defines"`

I think that you can use any command from *.pro files in that way.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I already managed it .I had to manualy run qmake and since that my problem passed