# Using boost/asio in QT

Tags: c++, qt, boost, boost-asio

I tried to include the asio library from boost in QT Creator 3.2.2 (based on QT5.3.2), but when I try to run the code it tells me that he tells me

```
(...) Error: boost/asio.hpp: No such file or directory
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
                         ^
```

I downloaded and unpacked the library based on this: [getting started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#get-boost)

I then tried to link it to my project using this:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Program Files\boost_1_57_0\boost
```

But aparently I am missing something, since it allways gives me this error when I hit on "run"

UPDATE: 
I tried to install it using [this guide](http://cpp-qt-mac-win.blogspot.de/2011/10/qt-boost-for-beginners-step-by-step.html) and can't run the example project as well, also because of a "not found" error

Comment: have you tried adding the path to the include without the boost directory, that is: INCLUDEPATH += C:\Program Files\boost_1_57_0?

Comment: yeah, I did this before but with the same effect.

Comment: I think the problem may be caused by the space in "Program Files", you could try [adding quotes to the path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717359/in-a-qt-project-how-to-add-include-path-to-pro-under-windows-where-the-path-con) (or in case it does not work, moving the boost files to a directory without spaces).

Comment: I tried that, but that did nothing

Comment: Try both!The boost include files are in the boost directory so you've gone one level too far and windows still doesn't like spaces in path names see:  [variable-with-spaces-in-the-path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851012/set-a-path-variable-with-spaces-in-the-path-in-a-windows-cmd-file-or-batch-file)