# how to use a library in c++ Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, include, qt-creator, dicom

I downloaded a library for processing DicOM FILES .
The tree of library is :

```
|--include
        |-----dicom.h
        |-----dicomcfg.h
|--lib
     |--------dicomsdl.lib
```

But I do not know how to use and built-in Qt Creator .
If anyone can help me I will be very grateful.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Post the code snippets you have tried yet.

Comment: thank you the name of library is dicomsdl http://code.google.com/p/dicomsdl/

Comment: What's your problem? Can't you build the library or you can't use it withing Qt Creator?

Comment: i can't using with Qt creator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you use qmake as your build system.
To link your "external" library you need following changes in your .pro file:

```
#path to includes directory of your library, qmake will try to find includes there
INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/library/include

#path to pre-compiled library directory
LIBS += -L/path/to/precomp/library

#link your pre-compiled library, -l<library name> w/o .so, .a, .lib, lib- prefix
LIBS += -ldicomsdl
```

Maybe you'll need to build the library from source with your compiler. There could be some troubles if compilers don't match.

Comment: Even worse, there may be troubles even if the compile options are not the same (OTOH, if that's just an import library - i.e. it provides only trampolines to the corresponding dll - there shouldn't be big issues).

Comment: @RaccoonMonk thank you but i get this error :-1: erreur : LNK1146:  no argument specified with option '/LIBPATH:'

Comment: I'd like to see your .pro file. It looks like you've made some mistakes.

Comment: @RaccoonMonk  it looks like this:                                                     #path to includes directory of your library, qmake will try to find includes there
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Users\Symfony\Desktop\dicomsdl-0.79-x86-msvc-debug\include
#path to pre-compiled library directory
LIBS += -LC:\Users\Symfony\Desktop\dicomsdl-0.79-x86-msvc-debug\lib

#link your pre-compiled library, -l<library name> w/o .so, .a, .lib, lib- prefix
LIBS += -ldicomsdl

SOURCES += \
    exxample.cpp

Comment: instead of
C:\Users\Symfony\Desktop\dicomsdl-0.79-x86-msvc-debug\include
do 
/c/Users/Symfony/... and so on.
-LC:\Users\Symfony\Desktop\dicomsdl-0.79-x86-msvc-debug\lib too:
-L/c/...

Comment: @RaccoonMonk like this :                          
INCLUDEPATH += /c/Users/Symfony/Desktop/dicomsdl-0.79-x86-msvc-debug/include

LIBS += -L/c/Users/Symfony/Desktop/dicomsdl-0.79-x86-msvc-debug/lib


LIBS += -ldicomsdl      it doesn 't work

Comment: @user2972323 What's the output? Fyi no spaces in paths are allowed. Maybe no dots too. Put the library somewhere else.

Comment: LINK : fatal error lnk1146: no argument specified with option "/LIBPATH:

Comment: i have change the name to dicomsdl     the output is : :-1: erreur : dependent '..\..\Desktop\dicomsdl-0.79-x86-msvc-debug\include\dicom.h' does not exist. and in #include "dicom.h" he tell no such file or directory

Comment: I still think it's about the paths. Avoid to use all metacharacters or escape them with "\".

Comment: i use  : /c/Users/Symfony/Desktop/dicomsdl/include
-L/c/Users/Symfony/Desktop/dicomsdl/lib

Comment: Seems good. Now if these paths are in .pro and the folder is actually there, there might be a problem with qt creator itself. It could cache the config. You need to clean it. Try Build/Clean All within Qt Creator menu.

Comment: now he dont know directory dicom.h  (#include "dicom.h" )  : no such file or directory

Comment: @user2972323 Put it somewhere you'll know for sure everything's right and does exist. Like C:\dicomsdl. Put all headers and the .lib file in this folder and do right paths in .pro file, i.e. /c/dicomsdl

Comment: the same problem 'dicom.h': No such file or directory .

Comment: This is impossible, therefore your paths are old. Most probably you need to clean the build just like I told you before. It still has old paths. You can also just delete the build directory.

Comment: .pro file :                                                #path to includes directory of your library, qmake will try to find includes there
INCLUDEPATH += /c/dicomsdl
#path to pre-compiled library directory
LIBS += -L/c/dicomsdl

#link your pre-compiled library, -l<library name> w/o .so, .a, .lib, lib- prefix
LIBS += -ldicomsdl
  and in  C:\dicomsdl directory i have put dicom.h & dicomcfg.h & dicomsdl.lib directly

Comment: @user2972323 Paths should be normal and between double quotes. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717359/in-a-qt-project-how-to-add-include-path-to-pro-under-windows-where-the-path-con) Sorry. For Windows I always use msys to build projects, that's why I didn't know that.